# How do I switch on CONFIG_CONTEXT_TRACKING in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, configuration

I want to switch on CONFIG_CONTEXT_TRACKING, I am able to find this config with a search in menuconfig but not able to turn it on.
I am also having difficulty in understanding the config options that CONTEXT_TRACKING depends on.
Can someone tell me step by step how to switch on this config?

Comment: It seems that you should turn it on via "Full dynticks CPU time accounting" (`VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN`). If you search for it with the `/` key in `make menuconfig` it will tell the whole path to the option.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile your own Linux kernel.

`CONTEXT_TRACKING` is an automatic setting, which is enabled if `VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN` is selected.

`VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN` is available under “General setup”, “CPU/Task time and stats accounting”, “Cputime accounting”, “Full dynticks CPU time accounting”. You can find this out by typing <kbd>/</kbd> and searching for `VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN` in `make menuconfig`:

[image: Search results for <code>VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN</code>]

Selecting this option, which is only possible on architectures with support for `CONTEXT_TRACKING`, will automatically enable `CONTEXT_TRACKING`:

[image: Cputime accounting option]

The availability of `VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN` depends on all of the following:

- `HAVE_CONTEXT_TRACKING` (automatically set on ARM, ARM64, MIPS, 64-bit PowerPC, 64-bit SPARC, 64-bit x86)
- `HAVE_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN` (indicates support for 64-bit `cputime_t`; automatically set on 64-bit architectures and architectures where the appropriate locking has been implemented, *i.e.* ARM and non-SMP MIPS)
- `GENERIC_CLOCKEVENTS` (automatically set on architectures supporting generic clock events, *i.e.* everything but Itanium)